# Deleting Picture Element using ArcPy in ArcGIS 10.3 Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, image, delete, element

I'm trying to delete a Picture Element from 45 MXDs. This code is a start for me:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"G:\PROJECTS\landuse\gis"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(
                r"G:\PROJECTS\landuse\gis\\" + mxdname)
    for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"PICTURE_ELEMENT"):
        if elm.name == "F:\GIS\practical_shapefile\notes\aer1_logo1.jpg":
            elm.sourceImage =r"F:\GIS\practical_shapefile\general\esd_logo1.jpg"
            mxd.save()
del mxd
```

I read:

- http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listlayoutelements.htm
- http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/pictureelement-class.htm

but didn't find any hint how to do it.

Comment: Don't think you can actually delete a layout element with arcpy.mapping. Maybe, you could try playing with its size? For instance, try setting its elementHeight/elementWidth to 0. Or, as you are probably already doing, try setting its source to an empty or even non-existent image. Just few hints that might work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you cannot add or remove picture elements using ArcPy. If it's acceptable you can use a work around and set the element height to 0.

```
pict = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "PICTURE_ELEMENT")[0]
pict.elementHeight = 0
```

Here's a red bar picture element which disappears once I set its height to zero. It sounds like you're working outside the mxd but if not make sure you refresh the view to see the results.

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes- i work on outside python file and i want to delete the image, then to export it with python- but with no red sign as you mention. how can do it?